How to delete user data from Firestore by their ID in FlutterFlow in with Cloud Functions?
I need to delete user data from Firestore in my FlutterFlow application. How can I do this with a Cloud Function?

Your question is not very clear. What type of Cloud Function? A callable one (that you call from the Flutter app)? What is the problem with the fact that "this solution was found that allows you to remove a user from Firebase Authentication."? You need to explain clearly what is the problem and what is your exact functional requirement. Please also read How do I ask a good question?

Hi Renaud!
I have solved the problem and attached the code below in the answer. The cloud function removes the user from Firebase Authentication and the users collection.

After trying various methods, this solution was found that allows you to remove a user from Firebase Authentication.
I created a Cloud Function to delete a user by his ID, and then call this from FlutterFlow.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// To avoid deployment errors, do not call admin.initializeApp() in your code

exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
     // Write your code below!
  console.log('Received data:', data);  // Add this for debugging
     const userId = data.userId;

  if (!context.auth) {
  console.log('userId is missing or empty');  // Add this for debugging
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', User is not authenticated');
     }
     // Check userId format
     if (typeof userId !== 'string' || userId.length === 0) {
  console.log(Invalid userId format:', userId);  // Add this for debugging
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', userId must be a non-empty string');
  }

  if (!userId) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', No userId provided');
  }

  try {
    // Check if user exists
    await admin.auth().getUser(userId);

    // Delete user from Firebase Authentication
    await admin.auth().deleteUser(userId);

    // Delete user data from Firestore
    await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).delete();

    console.log(`User ${userId} successfully deleted`);
    return { success: true, message: User successfully deleted' };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting user:', error);
    
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', User not found');
    } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-uid') {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Invalid userId');
    } else {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', `Error deleting user:${error.message}`);
    }
  }
  // Write your code above!
});

